# Regular expression couldn't match text when there is line break within it

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract strings based on a Regular Expression, however when new line exists within string.. Regular Expression doesnt handle

Regular Expression -

```
^Test\s[0-9]-[0-9]:.+?(?=\.)
```

Expression is simple, it matches any string that starts with Test followed by space and digit-digit and : followed by any text until .

This finds the text messages like below

```
Test 1-8: This is first test.
Test 9-8: This is second test and is OK.
Test 5-1:This is Test 1,3 three.
```

However when there is a text with a line break in below, above regular expression doesn't work.

```
Test 9-8: This is second test 
and is OK.
```

How should I handle this in my regular expression?

Comment: You have to enable multi-line in general, and this is application dependent - add to your question what you're using.

Comment: http://regexr.com/ ..  try here add your regex and string and try yourself

Comment: For the example @RïshïKêshKümar gives, you activate newline in the 'flag' button to the right top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` (used in `.+?(?=\.)`) does not match line break chars in non-POSIX regex engines (exact chars vary across regex libraries).

Use a negated character class `[^.]+` here:

```
^Test\s[0-9]-[0-9]:[^.]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T0GOvW/1/)

The `[^.]+` matches any 1 or more characters (including line breaks) other than a literal dot.

Comment: There are many implementations of regex where by default the regular expression matches are per line - it's really application dependent beyond the look ahead thing you mention.

Comment: @kabanus: The point I am making is that `.+?(?=\.)` will not match line breaks, but a `[^.]` matches the same text, but across lines. Whether it is used in a tool or code is irrelevant for now.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor.. Could you please check https://regex101.com/r/lBHNGG/1  .. How to handle in Regular expression to also match the first two messages in it?

Comment: Use [`^Test\s[0-9]-[0-9][0-8]?:[^.]+`](https://regex101.com/r/lBHNGG/2), add a `?` after `[0-8]` to make it match 1 or 0 occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

To match "any character, including newlines" you can use the following: `[\s\S]`, which means "any whitespace character and any non-whitespace character"... so effectively: everything.

Alternatively you could use the 's' flag: `/^Test\s[0-9]-[0-9]:.+?(?=\.)/s`. This will also include newlines for the dot.

The solution provided by @wiktor-stribiżew is more efficient though, so I would advice using that one.